# Not able to send dynamic javascript parameters when changing onclick function through javascript call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

Sample Code:

```
<img id="image" onclick="addDetails('1','2','3');" src="sample.png"/>

<script>
function addDetails(data1,data2,data3)
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        .....
        .....,
        success: function()
        {
            document.getElementById("image").onclick=function onclick(event){deleteDetails('data1','data2','data3');};
        }    
    });
}
</script>
```

In the above sample code i am making an ajax call on click of image and after successchanging the 
onclick function to deleteDetails. Both the functions addDetails and deleteDetails have same value as their parameter. so in the onclick function am trying to set the  deleteDetails with the  same parameters as of the called method.

The problem here is when i debugged it the actual function which binded with the onclick function is
deleteDetails('data1','data2','data3') insted of deleteDetails('1','2','3') . I tried all the possible string operators to print the value but its not happening.

Comment: You are passing in "strings" - pass in the object references, ie - remove the ''. deleteDetails(data1,data2,data3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arguments are variables, not "Strings" (only strings are wrapped in quotes)

```
document.getElementById("image").onclick = deleteDetails(data1, data2, data3);
```

Comment: hi, I have tried this option.  The function is binded as deleteDetails(data1, data2, data3) but the vales of the data1, data2 and data3 are not passed instead its searching in my html(document) for variables data1,data2 and data3

Comment: Sorry for the last comment it seems i have added '' to the data separately when i checked . Its working